# Overlay and image in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, overlay, css-position

I'm trying to show 16 by 16 pixel image at X=100 & Y=100 but am stuck. The image is to be displayed over the top of whatever is on the page. Altering the top and left properties don't do anything.

Whatever I do, the image seems to show up at pos 0,0.

```
shimDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    shimDiv.style.top = 100;
    shimDiv.style.left = 100;
    shimDiv.style.width = "1000px"; // todo: change me!
    shimDiv.style.height = "1000px"; // todo: change me!
    shimDiv.style.zIndex = 3;
    document.body.appendChild(shimDiv);
    $("#shim").append('<img id="icon" src="../Images/info.png" alt="todo:" />');
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing up plain JavaScript with jQuery? It seems unnecessarily complex, for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've not specified the units for the `top` and `left` positions:

```
shimDiv.style.top = '100px';
shimDiv.style.left = '100px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe this is an oversimplification, but this should accomplish what you are asking:

```
$('body').append('<img id="icon" src="../Images/info.png" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; z-index: 1000;" />');
```

It seems in your code sample that the creation code for the parent div element is missing, but the above code should be all that is necessary.

Hope that helps...